# Android Image not displayed

Tags: android, image

i'm unable to load image in the android application..(i'm very beginner in Android and Java) .. it is a very simple start-up app to display a image and a text message..

When application load (in emulator) i can see only the text msg and no image :(

Can you please help me..

here is my **layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is there any error in the logCat?

Comment: No error in the logcat file :(.. it compiles OK without any error but no image display - does it requires any "user-permission" to show images??

Comment: have tried cleaning your project.. do you allow automatic build?

Comment: yes, cleaned project several times and "allow automatic build" is checked -- is there anythign wrong here?

Comment: it's weird.. this should work fine.. try using `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo` in your `TextView` and remove the `ImageView` and see if the image is displayed..

Comment: thanks for your help.. fix it... code was creating new textview instead of using the textview which was overwritting the image 


TextView view = new TextView(this);
view.setText(sMsg);
setContentView(view);


replaced above with this one...
TextView tVote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVote);
tVote.setText(sms);

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you have the drawable folder in res and the logo image file is in that folder. Hope this help.

Comment: Hi.. folder does exists and file also (file name is logo.png). under "res" folder, there are 4 folders, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and each folder has this logo.png file - but it is not getting displayed !!